# Trying to Build Android AOSP Gingerbread to The Motorola Droid

Tags: android, android-build, android-source

I'm trying to build the AOSP Gingerbread for my Droid using [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=987286) to patch the source, but I'm getting this error:

```
Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:AOSP Nathan$ lunch generic_sholes-userdebug
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
build/core/product_config.mk:194: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[device/motorola/sholes/sholes.mk]]: "build/target/product/small_base.mk" does not exist.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'generic_sholes'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

Nathan-Camposs-MacBook-Pro:AOSP Nathan$
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you run source build/envsetup.sh prior to running lunch the build system collects up the product specs for each product, from files called vendorsetup.sh. This is the line in my envsetup.sh that searches for those files:

`# Execute the contents of any vendorsetup.sh files we can find.`
 `for f in /bin/ls vendor/*/vendorsetup.sh vendor/*/*/vendorsetup.sh device/*/*/vendorsetup.sh 2> /dev/null`

You should also see output from the script of each product that it finds. Either your vendorsetup.sh isn't being found by build/envsetup.sh or you have not created one to define your product, in which case, look at the other products vendorsetup.sh scripts for inspiration.